# Expectation value of exponential of a function - first two moments of function known

Tags: expectation

I have a function $f(t)$ and know that $\langle f(t)\rangle=0$ and $\langle f(t)f(t')\rangle=C(t-t')$;

Now i want to calculate:

$$\left\langle\exp\left(\int\limits_{0}^t f(t') \, \mathrm{d}t'\right)\right\rangle$$

I tried to look at the sum definition of the exponential but could do anything...

Any help?

Comment: What is $\langle f \rangle$?

Comment: Note that proper notation is $\langle f(t)\rangle,$ not $<f(t)>. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! $\left\langle f(t)\right\rangle$ dentoes the expectationvalue

Comment: @SeanRoberson : It means expectation of $f. \qquad$

Comment: Is the entire function $f$ supposed to be chosen randomly?

Comment: Hmm. Must be nonstandard notation. I'm used to $E(X)$ but hey, we learn something new!

Comment: yes, it's a real function where only these two moments are known

Comment: yeah...as a physicist the notation may anger the common mathematician :D

Answer (score 0):

I **think** what you mean is that $f$ is a stochastic process (rather than a function) of mean $0$ and covariance $C(t - t')$.  **If** it's a Gaussian process, that's all you need to determine it, but if it's non-Gaussian you really don't know enough to say anything about expectations of exponentials.  They might not even exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know assumed that $\left\langle f(t_1)f(t_2)....f(t_n)\right\rangle=0$ for $ n \ge 3$, which helps evaluating the integral easily!